# Can you make Entity Framework 6 database-first generated entities private?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 and database-first to generate my table entities. Is it possible to make the entities private?

This is my project setup:

- **Project.Core**

  - `DatabaseFirstContext.edmx`
  - `Service.cs`
  - `DomainModel.cs`
  - `Repository.cs`
- **Project.Web**

  - `HomeController.cs`

I would like my `Project.Web` to be able to see my `DomainModel.cs` but not the entities which the `DatabaseFirstContext.edmx` generates. The reason I would like to keep the EF6 generated entities in the `Project.Core` is because it is one less layer of mappings. This way the `Service.cs` can work directly with the generated entities. But I would like to prevent the `Project.Core` from exposing the generated entities to other projects and prevent other developers from exposing them.

Comment: Why not give them the `internal` access modifier?

Comment: yes, internal will work and thank you for linking the answer

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is weird to hide the entities. Anyways, you need `T4 Templates`.

A tutorial:
https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/entityframework/using-t4-templates-in-entity-framework

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/codegen/